# Basis for Kernel in function space

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials

Here is my problem:

Let $\Pi_2$ be the function space of all polynomials of max. grade 2,that are defined on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Let $G : \Pi_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be given as $f \stackrel{G}{\mapsto} f(1) $.

What is the basis of the $\ker(G)$ ?

---

My thoughts process is to find the set of the kernel and then find the basis to it.

The kernel is the set of functions which evaluate to zero. So:

$\ker(G):= \{ \ f \  | \ f(1) = 0\}  $ I dont know how to write this set more formally.

My next step would be to find the basis to this set.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)#Examples

Comment: Can you think of two simple polynomials of degree $\le 2$ that evaluate to zero when $x=1$?

Comment: $f(x) = x^2 -x +0  $ and $ g(x) = -x^2 +x $. Whats your point though ? I dont see the next step

Comment: What is the dimension of the domain and the range. How many elements will a basis for $\ker G$ have? Are the two polynomials you mentioned linearly independent? (Answer: no.)

Comment: well I'd argue that the dimension of the domain is 3 (since you have control over 3 variables to build the polynomial ) thus the basis needs to have 3 elements (correct ?), 
also wouldnt all polynomials in $\ker G$ be linearly independant since there are infinitely many ?

Comment: @copper.hat I have thought about it and it seems to me that the base of the ker would be the same as for the function space: $B_{\ker G} = \{ 1,x,x^2\} $ also I forgot to mention in the question that $\Pi_2$ is defined over $[-1,1]$ but that doesnt change any thing does it ?

Answer (score 2):

First$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}$ notice that $\Ima G = \mathbb{R}$ since $G(c) = c$, for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Now we can use the rank-nullity theorem to determine the dimension of $\Ker G$.

$$3 = \dim \Pi_2 = \dim \Ima G + \dim \Ker G = 1 + \dim\Ker G \implies \dim\Ker G = 2$$

Now find two simple linearly independent polynomials in $\Ker G$. For example, you can take $x-1$ and $(x-1)^2$. They are obviously not proportional since their degrees are not equal.

Thus, the set $\{x-1, (x-1)^2\} \subseteq \Ker G$ is a linearly independent set with cardinality equal to the dimension of the space. Hence, it is a basis for $ \Ker G$.

Comment: brilliant answer, I can pick whatever independant "kernel functions", right ?
otherwise: accepted !

Comment: @zython Yeah, sure. Any of these will also work: $\{x-1, x(x-1)\}$,  $\{x-1, 2x(x-1)\}$, $\{2(x-1), 4x(x-1) + (x-1)^2\}$. As noted by copper.hat, each of them has to be divisible by $x-1$, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another take to complement @mechanodroid's excellent answer.

If $p \in \ker G$ we must have $p(1) = 0$ and so $x-1$ must be a factor
of the polynomial. Similarly, if $x-1$ is a factor  of  a polynomial $p$
then we must have $p \in \ker G$.

Hence $\ker G = \{ p \in \Pi_2 | x-1 \text{ is a factor} \}
= \{ x \mapsto (x-1) q(x) | g \in \Pi_1 \}$ .

We can quickly check that the linear map $L :\Pi_1 \to \ker G$ given by
$(Lq)(x) = (x-1)q(x)$ is a bijection, hence $\dim \ker G = \dim \Pi_1 = 2$.

Furthermore, since $x \mapsto 1, x \mapsto  x$ forms a basis for
$\Pi_1$, then $L (x \mapsto 1), L(x \mapsto  x)$ forms a basis for
$\ker G$.

Hence $x \mapsto x-1, x \mapsto x(x-1)$ is a suitable basis.